# Variant of validation with singleton test sets

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, terminology, validation

Is the following approach to model validation somehow reasonable? And is there a name for that approach? We have 110 data points, iid assumption holds and we want to compare two predictive models M1 and M2. We randomly assign the data to a model estimation/training set $E=\{d_1,\dots,d_{100}\}$ and a test set $T=\{d_{101},\dots,d_{110}\}$. Then we estimate M1 and M2 10 times, based on 10 equally large subsets of $E$, i.e. $E_1=\{d_1,\dots,d_{10}\}, \dots ,E_{10}=\{d_{91},\dots,d_{100}\}$ and test their performance each at exactly one point of $T$. We test the fitted models based on $E_1$ at $d_{101}$ the fitted models based on $E_2$ at $d_{102}\dots$

At the end we calculate an average of the (mean) squared errors for both models. As we test at one point only, it is actually just an average of squared errors.

Comment: Is T time? If so, this sounds like time series cross-validation with a mean square error metric - https://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/tscv/

Comment: No, I edited the question. It is actually a test set but each member is only used once for a model estimated with 1/10th of the data.